# JTextField with transparent background not behaving well

Tags: java, swing, transparency, jtextfield

I am developing a chat app., where the user types all his info here, but the `JTextField` is not behaving really well, as shown in the image attached.

[image]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wildly guessing: the field's opacity isn't set correctly to false, which produces the artefacts. The snippet below works just fine:

```
JTextField name = new JTextField(20);
name.setOpaque(false);
JTextField pass = new JTextField(20);
pass.setOpaque(false);
pass.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
// being lazy: use SwingX 
JXPanel panel = new JXPanel();
BufferedImage back = XTestUtils.loadDefaultImage("moon.jpg");
panel.setBackgroundPainter(new ImagePainter(back));
panel.add(name);
panel.add(pass);
```

Comment: Thousands thanks to @klepatra, it works when I changed setOpaque(true) to false, thanks

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `JTextField repaint(), validate();` etc

`JTextField name = new JTextField();`
Create KeyTyped method then add in it
`name.repaint() name.validate() name.invalidate()`